Is vaping on Pesach allowed?
Are vapes kosher for Pesach being as the liquid, even if it would contain chometz, isn't fitting for a dog to eat?

dinonline and R Daniel Stein both forbid it without kosher supervision
R Daniel Stein

Additionally, the Magen Avraham (467:10) prohibits cigarettes
containing beer-soaked tobacco on Pesach, even though the tobacco is
presently inedible (see Beis Meir.) Rav Moshe Schick (Maharam Schick,
Orach Chaim 242) explains that since the beer-soaked tobacco is
designed for inhalation and it has a pleasant flavor when inhaled, the
tobacco can still be considered fit for consumption and remains
prohibited. This is presumably predicated upon the notion that
inhalation can sometimes be considered a form of imbibing (see also
Magen Avraham 210:9). Similarly, since the e-juice is intended for
inhalation and enjoyable when inhaled, it would retain its status as a
forbidden food and as a result it should require kashrus supervision.

dinonline:

E-cigarettes need to be certified kosher for Passover. because they
have various flavors, that come from a lot of places, and the persons
intention is to ingest it


Interesting. I suppose now we need to ask what is the bracha on vaping, are we allowed to vape on fast days, and does all vaping require a hechsher?
